# Setting up Digital Downloads using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, download

I'm pretty new to coding and have been teaching myself HTML, CSS and JS/JQuery through a few books and Codeacademy. I'm creating a website so my Dad can sell his music and I'm leaving the two things I find most daunting to last, namely preview streams and downloads.

I've been able to find some concise information about how to set up a streaming player and I just need to take the time to implement it but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on how to set up a digital download platform. Am I looking in the wrong place?

I have the space on the domain to host the music files and I imagined it would be achieved though some JS/JQuery magic but all I can seem to find are links to Wordpress plugins which I don't really understand how to use.

Can anyone help?

I'd also prefer to use Paypal as the payment method because he has an account already set up.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I would suggest you to use CMS (Like WordPress) which has great plugins available. Achieving digital media protection is not an easy thing to do.

You will have to take care of download, payment gateways, media protection etc stuff. Which from scratch can take over 5-6 months. You can simply use CMS and plugins and setup a store in few days :-)

Setup a wordpress blog and install this plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/music-store/). It has most of the things you need..

Spend the rest of the time on learning HTML5 and Javascript from beginning.

Good luck with your dad's website and learning.. All the best..

Regards,

Rahul

Comment: Wow thanks for the advice, thanks for giving me a definitive answer. I guess I'm going to just have to add learning about Wordpress to my list of things to do but if it can give me an easy way to get the downloads workin ill do it gladly.